# Passing Dataframes in classes and functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know this has probably be done to death, but im really struggling with the use of variables (dataframes) in classes and functions.
I have a created a small code example.
basically I want to

1. read a csv to a Dataframe via a button
2. show a label when a dataframe is read
3. ignore the label when no Dataframe is read or is empty
4. refresh the label every 1 seconds

What I am curious (read frustrated) about is how the dataframe in this code can pass from function to function without the use of globals. My error in the refresh function is that the dataframe is not seen as a dataframe type.

```
import sys
import io
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
import pandas as pd
import fsspec


text_label = ''
df_data = pd.DataFrame()

class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("gui.ui", self)

        self.df_data = self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.loadcsv)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.stop_app)
        self.label.setText(text_label)

        #refresh gui
        self.__timer = QTimer()
        self.__timer.timeout.connect(self.refresh_labels(self.df_data))
        self.__timer.start(1000)

        self.show()


    def loadcsv(self):
        filename = 'c://test/test.csv'
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)
        file_data = file_data.append(df)
        return file_data


    def refresh_labels(self, file_data):
        try:
            text_label = str(file_data.dtypes)
            self.label.setText(text_label)
        except:
            pass

    def stop_app(self):
        if QMessageBox.question(self, "Exit", "Close Program") != QMessageBox.No:
            qApp.quit()
        pass


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = UI()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind

it seems I didnt address the variable correctly as I had to include the classname before it.

in this case it was UI.df_data
I also didnt need to use different names as this name is valid throughout the class